# бесконечный цикл в кликере C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    system("title Cliker by DockedFerret800");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "\nЛевый кнопка мыши - Clicking; Правый ALT - Закрытие приложения.";

    while (1 != 0)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) // если нажат левый кнопка мыши делаем следующие:
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, 0, 0); //*нажимаем* левую клавишу мыши
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, NULL, NULL, 0, 0); //*Отпускаем* левую клавишу мыши             
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(43)) // если нажат клавиша C  делаем следующие:
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, NULL, NULL, 0, 0); //*нажимаем* левую клавишу мыши
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, NULL, NULL, 0, 0); //*Отпускаем* левую клавишу мыши
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RMENU)) //если нажат правый ALT делаем следующие:
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Это кликер , когда один раз нажимаю на левую кнопку мыши запускается бесконечный цикл, а решение чтобы кликер работал только когда зажата левая кнопка мыши не знаю.

Comment: ну слушайе, условие (1 != 0) всегда будет истинным, это тоже самое что `while(true)`, а у вас даже `break` в цикле нету

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` делает не то, что вы думаете, что он делает. используйте `GetKeyState`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: При использовании GetKeyState не работает на зажатия.